# Blank output when trying to reverse string

Tags: python

So I'm creating a basic program that decrypts and encrypts passwords. I have functions that work, but I'm having an issue when I try to reverse the string return of the decryption function. Here's some of the relevant code. I've confirmed the functions are working correctly and returning the correct strings.

```
print("Reverse encryption? (Y/N)")
reverse = input()
print()
if E_D == 'E':
    print("Enter the password to be encrypted.")
    password = input()
    print()
    print("Your encrypted password is:")
    encrypted_password = encryption(password, key1, key2, reverse)
    print(encrypted_password)
    print()
elif E_D == 'D':
    print("Enter the encrypted password including all spaces.")
    encrypted_password = input()
    print()
    print("After decryption, the password is:")
    if reverse == 'N':
        orig_password = decryption(encrypted_password, key1, key2, reverse)
        print(orig_password)
        print()
    elif reverse == 'Y':
        orig_password = decryption(encrypted_password, key1, key2, reverse)
        print(orig_password[::-1])
        print()
    print()
```

I get the correct output when the input for the "reverse" variable is "N", but if the input is "Y", then I just get a blank output. Just nothing prints. As you can see with the last few lines, the only difference when reverse = 'Y' is that the function return string is reversed.

Comment: Are you sure `decryption` returns a string if `reverse` is passed in as `Y`?

Comment: did you try to print something (e.g `print('test')` in the elif statement to see if the code even reaches the `elif reverse == 'Y'`?

Comment: You're making this unnecessarily complicated and easy to break. `reverse` is expected to have a value of either "Y" or "N" which your encryption and decryption functions need to handle. What happens if the user enters a lower-case "y" or "n"? In that case your second `if` block will never decrypt and print anything. Is that perhaps what happened to you?